# ng-view not loading the template (no web server running)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

I have tried all the answers to similar questions without success. I have a project directory structure like this:

- app

  > config.js

  - Shared

    > Layout.html
  - Home

    > Index.html

Here config.js, Shared and Home are at the same level.

My Layout.html has the code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="app">
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Assets/ng/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../Assets/ng/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../config.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
         <a href="#/">Home</a>
         <section ng-view></section>
    </body>
    </html>
```

My Index.html just has the words "Home view".

config.js file:

```
angular.module("app", ['ngRoute')

.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider
    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: '../Home/Index.html'
    })
    .otherwise({
        redirecTo: '/'
    });
}]);
```

However, this does not show anything in the `<section></section>`. There is no exception thrown. One thing, btw, is that I'm not running a web server. I'm just opening my Layout.html in Chrome and then click on the link but the template doesn't load.

When the page is opened in Chrome url in the browser is something like

```
file:///Users/user.name/Desktop/folder1/subfolder1/app/Shared/Layout.html#/
```

What's wrong with my approach? Thanks.

Comment: `ng-route` **requires** a web server, it cannot be run from `file://` urls, because it uses ajax to fetch the template partials.

Comment: Thanks Claies, will run a server.

Comment: if you wish you can use python to set up a local server effortlessly. simply use python -m SimpleHTTPServer[port number]. the current directory on the command line will become the root directory : http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/modules-in-python/how-to-use-simplehttpserver/

Comment: Thanks Kiran, this is really neat. I'm also thinking of using $serviceProvider to do it completely client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bro please use local server to load your application. Either use visual studio or if you know nodejs than use that.
You are loading it directly from file system.

Comment: Darn, thanks Amit. I will run a nodejs server. Thanks very much!

Comment: my pleasure broo :)